# Parse HTML in GET with javascript to file

Tags: javascript

I have a function which calls a script with this information in the GET:

```
color = color_class(statistics[0]);
class = get_class(statistics[0]);
class = '<font style="color:'+color+';">'+class+'</font>';

switch(stage){
    case 1: call_file('tut_class.php?choice='+class,'main'); break;
}
```

This looks like this:

```
 <font style="color:#0d84b6;">Class One</font>
```

But in the Console it shows like this:

```
tut_class.php?choice=%3Cfont%20style=%22color:   //the rest is missing
```

And so i cannot obtain it in the PHP script to display. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: try setting the entire string into one variable beforehand

Comment: well whats point in calling a span class when the colour is not going to be set in the CSS file.

Comment: @pandavenger didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder ahh of course its so obvious now you said that.. jeese brain fart moment for me :P

Comment: change your < and > with the escape strings... at this point, I'm suggesting some things I would try to do... IDK if they would work XD

Comment: i changed it to :
call_file('tut_class.php?color='+color+'&class='+class,'main');  still don't work though it stops at color=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the string before adding it to the URL with [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), and later use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to unescape it.

Edit: oops, you are writing javascript. You should use javascript's encodeURIComponent to encode the string, and not PHP's urlencode.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't 'class' a reserved variable name? I'd change that to something else...

EDIT: Sorry, [apparently](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm) that's only true with ecmascript, not javascript

Comment: It may, but it won't work for all of your visitors.  IIRC, MSIE throws an error when it encounters variables named 'class'.  MDN has [a list of reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Comment: Also, I think it looks like the colon is the problem. It's usually used to separate a hostname from port number, amongst other, authentication related methods. Have you tried escaping the colon, with %3A ?